# Could i "Publish" a Open-Source Game/Software on a Platform without consens of the Development Team

Tags: open-source-software, publishing

If i saw a Software or Game that is Open-Source (like on GitHub).
Could i be something like a "Publisher" and take this Open-Source Game and put it on a Platform (like Steam) and put my Number as a Publisher without a consensus of the Developers of the Software/Game?

I saw that a Game under GPL on Github, that was make Open-Source after a it was already Published by another Company, was put on Steam (in a very broken State, which results in Work in the Developer Team that they respond to issues that this version has) from an "Random-Guy"

Example is [Warzone 2100](https://github.com/Warzone2100/warzone2100) which was Release in 3 March 1999 by Eidos Interactive, developed by   Pumpkin Studios. This was then Open-Soure in 2004. Recently i saw it on Steam and was digging a bit and saw that many People had issues and was saying that this shouldn't be on Steam. I saw that there the Publisher was a Single-Person which just put it on Steam. In the GitHub Tickets i also saw that the developers don't agree with this being on Steam. But it isn't taken down till know.

So my Question is: Could i just put some Open-Source Software (which was maybe already published by another Company) on a Platform?

For Example: Like for Example i could take the Game "freeCiv" and put myself as the "Main-Developer" and "Publisher" on a Platform like Steam and upload an Older/buggy Version?

Comment: I think the "main developer" part may be misleading, unless you can prove that most of the commits or a bulk of the work was in fact done by you.

Comment: Can you add a jurisdiction please?

Comment: @Andrew, well i don't really know what jurisdiction i should put it. I'm from Germany but Platforms Like Steam or other Distribution Platforms are more in the USA.
RonBeyer, well in the example i think that isn't the case due to the Fact it was firstly made by an Company with many developers. After that it was OpenSource and even there he doesn't show up anywhere

Comment: Is there a specific Open Source license you are interested in? There are numerous licenses that have different implications in this scenario.

Comment: This example Case is GPLv2. Most cases i found where GPLv2